# Juju and MAAS: ERROR No matching node is available - with Ready nodes

Tags: juju, maas

I have four nodes in the "Ready" state, and I am still getting the following error when trying to bootstrap:

```
ERROR No matching node is available.
```

The server is running 13.04 with Juju 0.7.

I have been walking through the instructions on the MAAS site: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/juju-quick-start.html

I also tried following the instructions to install the latest version of Juju (1.10.x) as described on https://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started/, but then I ran into some other errors, including "error: no tools available" when trying to bootstrap and "use of closed network connection" when trying to sync-tools.

How can I get a simple MAAS + Juju setup going for testing?

Answer (score 1):

You may have hit [bug 1064291](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1064291). This occurs if you have machines that aren't amd64 or have less than 512M of memory. The workaround is to bootstrap with constraints turned off:

```
juju bootstrap --constraints "arch=any mem=0"
```

If this works for you, please mark the bug as "affects me too".